# Yocto: how to use a custom layer to stop an existing layer from appending to a file

Tags: yocto

I've been provided a distribution/package that uses yocto project to build an embedded Linux image, but I need to make a few small changes. I want to do this by adding my own layer.

The problem: there is one recipe that appends a line to the fstab file. The recipe is:

```
meta-virtualization/recipes-core/base-files/base-files_3%.bbappend
```

and the contents of this file:

```
do_install_append() {
    if echo "${DISTRO_FEATURES}" | grep -q 'xen'; then
        echo "xenfs   /proc/xen   xenfs   defaults   0   0" >> ${D}${sysconfdir}/fstab
    fi
}
```

My requirement is that this xenfs line does not end up in the fstab file of the final image.

I've tried creating my own layer and recipe to overwrite the fstab file:

```
meta-mylayer/recipes-core/base-files/base-files_3%.bbappend
meta-mylayer/recipes-core/base-files/base-files/base-files/fstab
```

With contents:

```
FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}/${PN}:"
```

and

```
# my fstab to overwrite the one with xenfs
/dev/root / auto defaults 1 1
proc /proc proc defaults 0 0
devpts /dev/pts devpts mode=0620,gid=5 0 0
tmpfs /run tmpfs mode=0755,nodev,nosuid,strictatime 0 0
tmpfs /var/volatile tmpfs defaults 0 0
```

However this doesn't work as the xenfs line is just appended to my fstab file!
How can I stop this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pointed out in the comments: **cp should be used instead of cat**. The important point here is that this do_install_append() is called after the existing do_install_append(), which was not the case in the first attempt as seen in the question.

---

My current solution involves writing to the fstab file a second time, in a similar manner as the original recipe does it:

Create two files in base-files of the custom layer:

```
meta-mylayer/recipes-core/base-files/base-files_3%.bbappend
meta-mylayer/recipes-core/base-files/base-files/fstab.overwrite
```

with the contents of base-files_3%.bbappend:

```
FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}/${PN}:"
SRC_URI += " file://fstab.overwrite"

do_install_append() {
    if echo "${DISTRO_FEATURES}" | grep -q 'xen'; then
        cp fstab.overwrite ${D}${sysconfdir}/fstab
    fi
}
```

where the contents of fstab.overwrite replaces the current fstab file with the unwanted appends.

Comment: I will accept any answer that improves on this solution.  Best solution would be one where the append from the meta-virtualization layer is prevented.

Comment: Your solution is quite good. The problem is that yocto doesn't allow to manually disable or override (it works, but works strangely and inconsistently) any existing function from other layer, you either disable the whole layer, or use everything it provides altogether.
But I don't understand why have you decided to use `cat` in place of `cp`?

Comment: I didn't even think of using cp...  probably because my first effort to copy over the file didn't work. But you're right, it should work here. Thanks!